# External work in raising a stone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

Suppose a person is raising a stone upwards against the force of gravity. The common methodology that is followed is this: Since gravity pulls by $mg$ force,the person has to put $mg$ force in opposite direction to make the stone move with constant velocity making the external work of agent $mgh$. But here is a doubt of mine. Since a person is holding the stone,there must be a normal reaction between the palm of the hand and stone. Now, the forces acting on stone are gravity $mg$,normal reaction $N$ and force of agent $F$,so the required equation should be $N+F=mg$. I don't know why normal reaction is taken into account in normal methodology. Or i am being wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

The normal force between the hand and the stone is the same thing as the "force of agent".

"Normal force" is just a blanket term that applies to the component of the force of interaction between two surfaces that is perpendicular to the surfaces at the point of contact. So the "force if agent" in your case is a normal force, but putting both $N$ and $F$ is double counting the single force the person exerts on the rock.

Comment: Thanks a lot but please tell me if i am being wrong. Any two objects in contact will apply normal force to each other. Here in our case,the stone is on our hand,so there is a normal force on stone for sure,but now we are again raising it,so we are giving extra force as well. Like consider the case if a book placed on a table,the table is stationary still it gives a normak force,but we are in contact with the stone and lifting it at the same time.

Comment: @madness Does 'lifting' include acceleration, or is it at constant velocity?

Comment: Constant velocity.

Comment: @madness They are the same force. It's like how weight is a vertical force. You don't have two forces: the "vertical force" and weight. It's just a classification. In this case the force between your hand and the rock is a normal force. "The normal force" isn't an extra force; it's just a classification/label you can apply to forces, just like the terms "horizonal force", "vertical force", "centripetal force", etc. It's just an indicator of direction.

Comment: Thanks but i don't understand one thing,how can normal force raise a stone uowards?I mean a book on a table also feels normal force but normal force doesn't  nake itmove uoward,but here we are moving the stone upwards,but according to you here,it is the normal force which is moving the stone upwards.

Comment: @madness I'll emphasize it again: "normal" is just an indicator of **direction**. In your table example, there is a force between the table and the book, and this is a normal force because it is perpendicular to the table/book interface. In the rock lifting example, there is a force between your hand and the rock, and this is a normal force because it is perpendicular to the hand/rock interface. They are *different* forces despite both being perpendicular to a surface. Just like how weight is a vertical force, but it isn't "the vertical force".

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out,it seems i had a major misconception as taught by our teachers. A question:does that mean normal force is the net force of all the forces acting perpendicular to the surface of an object?

Comment: @madness I suppose so. Usually it is reserved for forces that are perpendicular to the surface as well as arising from the interaction between two surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

@Biophysicist is right. I am adding some more points to clarify your doubt.
The basic concept is that the Normal Reaction force is electromagnetic in nature, i.e., it arises due to interaction at the atomic/subatomic level. It can **not** simply be calculated by any predefined equation like $\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}$ unlike gravitational force. Gravitational force can be calculated using a predefined equation like $\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$. The $mg$ is actually $m(\frac{GM_{earth}}{R_{earth}^2})$. I want to clarify one misconception that $N = mg$ because of action reaction pair. It is *not* true. The hidden piece of information in Newton's 3rd law is that the action and reaction forces must be of same nature. Electromagnetic force and gravitational force are not of same nature. Hence $N$ and weight are **not** action reaction pairs. Rather, the force exerted by earth on stone and the force exerted by stone on earth are action reaction pairs. $N$ is named normal *reaction* because it is due to contact force between two surfaces. So, contact force exerted by stone on ground and normal reaction exerted by ground on stone are action reaction pairs. Now, coming back to calculating $N$. $N$ can be calculated by observing the state of the object. When the stone is kept on the ground, we can observe that it is in rest. So, we can tell "no matter what be the complex molecular/atomic interactions, as I can see the object at rest, the net *external* force must be $0$ ". The external forces are $N$ (normal reaction on stone from ground) and $mg$ (force exerted on stone by earth). So $N - mg = m(0) = 0$ or $N = mg$. When we lift the stone, we can similarly tell "I don't care about the complicated interactions at atomic level, as I can see the object at motion, the net force must be according to Newton's 2nd law". So, $N - mg = ma$ or $N = m(g+a)$. The term used for this kind of behaviour of $N$ is "self-adjusting" nature. To understand this imagine you and your friend sitting on a bed. Suppose your weight is $50 kgwt$ and that of your friend is $70 kgwt$. Both of you are at rest. If $N$ would be $70$ for you then you would bounce but that does not happen. That's self adjusting nature.

Answer (score -1):

1. What you are saying seems correct to me that there is already the Normal force with the same magnitude as the gravitational force mg on the particle/mass you are lifting.
   BUT it is only right till the time you hold it.
   It is justified as long as you hold it(just hold it still in one place, and the mass is not moving). Now, since the acceleration is zero, the only forces acting on the mass you are holding are normal and gravitational.

Newton's second and third law satisfied (action-reaction pair and the net force is 0 since net acceleration while only holding is 0)

2. When you are trying to lift the mass, you need to accelerate it from its rest position in your hand, it has some inertia(inherent property of mass). SO, we need to apply a force on it, which you termed "extra" apart from the normal reaction(which you denoted as F)

In all, the action-reaction pair cancel out each other whether you are holding your mass or accelerating it.

But, there is the force you apply to it to change its momentum.
Let that force be F(which you said extra-to lift the mass-to accelerate it from rest resulting from action-reaction)

NOTE: You are applying a net force of N+Force(to accelerate from rest)>mg if F>0.
So, there is a net force.

The equation will be:
N+F-mg=ma(net)

N+F=m(g+a)

Since N=mg

F=ma(net)

So, your N component is resolved by the mg.

Also, in your equation,(which is wrong), N+F=mg, you are stating that if F is not equal to 0, then N is less than mg, but N and mg are action-reaction pairs.

It wont sink in at once-read it again,
Good Day!

EDIT 1:
See to make an object move at a constant velocity, it first needs to accelerate to that velocity in some earlier time, then the net force =0 can be done via the intervention of you.

EDIT 2:
As S Das pointed out, I would first like to say that I know what I had done. I did it just to make this thing simpler for the questioner. I have put it in the comments section that N and mg are not action-reaction pair.

Comment: In your 2nd paragraph,you assumed that the block will move with accelaration.I agree that upward force will be slightly greater than $mg$ to overcome inertia,but let's ignore that negligible force. I mentioned in my post that the block has to move with constant velocity and so resultant force has to be $0$ but you already took acceleration into account as seen from your answer. Also i didn't mean the extra $F$ to be the force required to just overcome inertia,i meant it as the force required to keep the stone moving. Also why $N=mg$?As i mentioned here both $N$ and $F$ are working at a time.

Comment: Maybe i am assuming that mere normal force can't take an object upward due to drawing lines of correlation between a staionary table with a book and this example.Will be helpful of you can show me any example with some animation where normal force is taking a stone upward as @BioPhysicist said.

Comment: Okay then. 
Let me clear this
Normal Reaction and Gravitational Force are not A-R pairs, since N is electrostatic and mg is gravitational. 
imagine a block lying on the ground.
So, it is not accelerating, hence F net=0
So, mg-N=0 (or N-mg=0), and so mg=N
This is a consequence of zero acceleration observed of not moving object that N=mg.
Imagine it in your hand. There too, when you are just holding it, it is not moving, so acceleration is 0, so f net=0. See, the normal reaction DID NOT MOVE THE BLOCK UPWARD DESPITE EXISTING. It was countered by the weight force (Equal in magnitude only)

Comment: Suppose there is a block mass 1kg. mg=1N(newton). Normal=1N(newton) (since a=0 as observed in the unmoving state of the block, indicating the equivalence of both the forces).
Now, we apply another force of 8Newton upward. Earlier, it was not moving. Now, since 8+N>mg, there is a net acceleration -8m/s^2. Net force is 8+N-mg=m*a(net). Since N=mg(observed), so 8=m*a(net) in the end. 
In your equation, agent force F is what YOU CONSCIOUSLY apply to bring that block up(different from normal reaction). So you need to account that IF F>0, then the equation you wrote is invalid.

Comment: Ok but the moment you wrote $N-mg+F=ma$(net),you are assuming block is moving with accelaration $a$ whereas i clearly mentioned it has to move with constant velocity.

Comment: coming to the point of how to drive something with a constant velocity, dp/dt=0 or change in momentum over time(defined as accelaration*mass hence), the net force of the system has to be 0 and the object must already be moving at a constant velocity.
Eg: you want to drive an object at 27 m/s, then drop the object in freefall for 2.7s. The velocity achieved at the end=27m/s, but the instant that happens, apply the force of 9.81m/s^2. Then, the object will be moving at a constant speed, but the force net is 0

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487450/how-can-a-body-have-constant-velocity-when-net-force-on-it-is-zero

https://questionfun.com/if-an-object-is-moving-at-constant-velocity-what-is-the-net-force/

https://www.restaurantnorman.com/when-you-apply-a-constant-force-to-an-object-does-the-object-move-at-a-constant-velocity-or-does-its-velocity-increase/

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86626/constant-velocity-force

Comment: these are some useful links

Comment: Force is not a property possessed by an object, but rather something you do to an object that results in the object accelerating (changing its speed), given by the equation F = ma.

Forces cause acceleration, not the other way around. This means that if you observe an object accelerating, then it implies a force is acting on the object to cause such an acceleration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132357/discussion-between-aveer-and-madness).

Comment: It is **wrong** to say "$N = mg$ (action reaction pair)". See my post for clarification.

Comment: @SDas i admitted having said it 
just said it to keep it simple

Comment: i also told that it is a self adjusting nature force since only just as much is required to keep the mass on the table is exerted